# Redirect 404 errors without rewriting the URL

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, rewrite, url, http-status-code-404

Is it possible to have an erroneous URL remain in the address bar while redirecting the user to a URL within my domain?  I want www.domain.com/forum to be the actual site being served in all 404 circumstances but I don't want the referring URL to be rewritten (other than the domain portion, which is being done on the registrar level).

This is my current .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On

RedirectMatch permanent ^/$ http://www.domain.com/forum/

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .* http://www.domain.com/forum/ [L,R]
```

Comment: Do you actually mean an [`ErrorDocument`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#errordocument) directive?

Answer (score 1):

You want to send 404 errors up to your application? Easy enough. You need to specify an existing file, though. For example:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /forum/index.php [L]
```

Comment: Doesn't that accomplish the same thing, as far as the URL bar is concerned?

Comment: @KnocksX It's not sending a redirect response, which is what changes the URL bar.

Comment: I think I spoke too soon.  This breaks the previous rule and the www is not always added anymore.  The forum also loses all formatting and is loaded without css.